# Pass object value as arguments to a function

Tags: python

Is there a way to pass a class as an argument to a function I've craeted?

for example:

If I have a class:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self._x = x
        self,_y = y
        self,_z = z
```

and some function:

```
def function(x,y,z):
    print(x,y,z)
```

is there a way to pass the object as arguments to the function?

```
tmp = a(1,2,3)

function(tmp)
```

Edit:

I shall clerify my question:

In a case where I do not want to access the objects variables directly but by functions such as a.getX or a.getY.

Is it still possiable to pass the class to the cuntion and whiting the function preform the a.getX and a.getY functions?

```
def function(a):
    print(a.getX, a.getY)
```

Comment: Yes. What errors are you seeing? `function` takes three parameters, by the way

Comment: You have written `self,_y` and `self,_z` instead of `self._y` and `self._z`

Comment: You can, of course, just write `def function(a): print(a.getX(), a.getY())`, but you have to add `()` to the method calls (assuming `getX` is a getter method). But then again, getter methods are not really a thing in Python. Just access `a._x` directly.

Answer (score 2):

If your function takes three parameters `x, y, z`, and you want those to be the corresponding `x, y, z` values of your class instance, you can either pass those explicitly to the function...

```
tmp = A(1, 2, 3)
func(tmp.x, tmp.y, tmp.z)
```

... or you could make your class implement the `__iter__` method and pass it as `func(*tmp)` to automatically unpack the `x, y, z` attributes to the three parameters:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.x, self.y, self.z])

def func(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)

func(*tmp)
```

The latter of course only works if the `__iter__` method returns the attributes in the same order as they are expected by the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the `__dict__` on desired variables but the names must be the same:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
def function(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)

tmp = a(1, 2, 3)
func(**tmp.__dict__)
#(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Nice. Also probably more universally applicable for different functions than my approach (parameter names might always match, but always same order is unlikely). You could even create a decorator to do this automatically for instances of certain classes: `@unpack(A) def foo(x, y, z): ...` then call just as `func(tmp)`

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Python is an object.

Currently, `function` takes three parameters, but nothing is preventing a class instance from being one of them

Maybe you're looking for this

```
def function(foo):
    print(foo._x, foo._y, foo._z)

tmp = a(1,2,3)
function(tmp)
```

If your code has errors, check the syntax of `self,_y` and replace the comma

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to pass the object as arguments to the function?

Yes, if you define your function to receive one argument:

```
def f(some_a):
    print(some_a)
```